# Using Icecuim but hangs to load json file

Tags: json, kendo-ui, icenium

I am using the icenium weather example from telerik platorm icenium.com to load a data file json for an test app I am doing 
my json is as follows

```
[
    {

    "screen_id": "course_outline",
    "screen_title": "NICMA Child Minding App - Course Outline",
    "screen_display_type": "/json_schema/P14_navigation.schema.json",
    "updated": "1371030938",
    "author": [
        {
        "author_name": "Andrew Moran",
        "author_url": "http://people.learningpool.com/user/id"
        }
    ],
    "comments": "authoring tool metadata, not used in app",
    "authoring_tool": {
        "version": "x.x",
        "href": ""
    },
    "copyright": "2013 - Learning Pool",
    "screen_content": {
        "screen_title": "Child Minding Navigation",
        "start_text": "Text at the start of the screen",
        "navigation_items": [
                {
                    "screen_id": "food_hygiene_legislation_doc",
                    "screen_display_type": "/json_schema/P03_content_screen.schema.json",
                    "display_text": "Home"
                }
            ],

        "end_text": ""
    }

  ]
```

I just made a copy of the weather funciton and named it course-outline.js
and added it into my scripts

```
(function (global) {
        var WeatherViewModel,
            app = global.app = global.app || {};

        WeatherViewModel = kendo.data.ObservableObject.extend({
            weatherDataSource: null,

            init: function () {
                var that = this,
                    dataSource;

                kendo.data.ObservableObject.fn.init.apply(that, []);

                dataSource = new kendo.data.DataSource({
                    transport: {
                        read: {
                            url: "data/course_outline.json",
                            dataType: "json"
                        }
                    }
                });

                that.set("weatherDataSource", dataSource);
            }
        });

        app.weatherService = {
            viewModel: new WeatherViewModel()
        };
    })(window);
```

But for some reason when i click the weather button now it hangs even though ive told the template to find screen_title any ideas

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
        <title></title>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <link href="kendo/styles/kendo.mobile.all.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
        <link href="styles/main.css" rel="stylesheet" />

        <script src="cordova.js"></script>
        <script src="kendo/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="kendo/js/kendo.mobile.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&sensor=true"></script>
      <script src="scripts/course-outline.js"></script>

        <script src="scripts/login.js"></script>
        <script src="scripts/location.js"></script>

        <script src="scripts/app.js"></script>

    </head>
    <body>
        <!--Home-->
        <div id="tabstrip-home"
            data-role="view"
            data-title="Home">

            <div class="view-content">
                <h1>Welcome!</h1>
                <a id="skin-change" data-role="button" data-click="app.changeSkin">Flat</a>
                <p>
                    Icenium&trade; enables you to build cross-platform device applications regardless of your
                        development platform by combining the convenience of a local development toolset with the
                        power and flexibility of the cloud.
                </p>
                <div class="img"></div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <!--Login-->
        <div id="tabstrip-login"
            data-role="view"
            data-title="Login"
            data-model="app.loginService.viewModel">

            <div class="view-content">
                <div class="logo"></div>
                <h3 data-bind="invisible: isLoggedIn">Enter your credentials:</h3>
                <h1 class="welcome" data-bind="visible: isLoggedIn">Welcome, <span data-bind="text: username"></span>!
                </h1>
                <div class="buttonArea">
                    <input type="submit" id="logout" data-role="button" data-bind="click: onLogout, visible: isLoggedIn" class="login-button" value="Logout" />
                </div>

                <form data-bind="events: { keyup: checkEnter }">
                    <ul data-role="listview" data-style="inset" data-bind="invisible: isLoggedIn">
                        <li>
                            <label>
                                Username
                                    <input type="text" data-bind="value: username" />
                            </label>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <label>
                                Password
                                    <input type="password" data-bind="value: password" />
                            </label>
                        </li>
                    </ul>

                    <div class="buttonArea">
                        <input type="submit" id="login" data-role="button" data-bind="click: onLogin, invisible: isLoggedIn" class="login-button" value="Login" />
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>

        </div>

        <!--Location-->
        <div id="tabstrip-location"
            data-role="view"
            data-title="Location"
            data-init="app.locationService.initLocation"
            data-show="app.locationService.show"
            data-hide="app.locationService.hide"
            data-model="app.locationService.viewModel"
            data-stretch="true">

            <div id="no-map" data-bind="invisible: isGoogleMapsInitialized">
                Location requires internet connection to display the map.
            </div>
            <div id="map-search-wrap" data-bind="visible: isGoogleMapsInitialized">
                <button id="map-navigate-home" data-bind="click: onNavigateHome"></button>
                <form onsubmit="return false;">
                    <input id="map-address" type="search" data-bind="value: address" placeholder="Address" />
                    <input id="map-search" type="submit" value="" data-bind="click: onSearchAddress" />
                </form>
            </div>
            <div id="map-canvas" data-bind="visible: isGoogleMapsInitialized"></div>

        </div>

        <!--Weather-->
        <div id="tabstrip-weather"
            data-role="view"
            data-title="Weather"
            data-model="app.weatherService.viewModel">

            <div class="weather">
                <p class="weather-title">Course Title</p>

                <div class="separator">
                    <div class="dark"></div>
                    <div class="light"></div>
                </div>

                <ul class="forecast-list"
                    data-role="listview"
                    data-bind="source: weatherDataSource"
                    data-template="weather-forecast-template">
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>

        <!--Weather forecast template-->
        <script type="text/x-kendo-tmpl" id="weather-forecast-template">
            <div>
                <div class="position-left">
                    <span class="weather-info date">${screen_title}</span>
                </div>
                <div class="position-right">
                    <span class="weather-info temperature high">${screen_title}<sup>&deg;</sup></span>
                    <span class="weather-info temperature low">${screen_title}<sup>&deg;</sup></span>
                </div>

            </div>
        </script>

        <!--Layout-->
        <div data-role="layout" data-id="tabstrip-layout">

            <!--Header-->
            <div data-role="header">
                <div data-role="navbar">
                    <span data-role="view-title"></span>
                </div>
            </div>

            <!--Footer-->
            <div data-role="footer">
                <div data-role="tabstrip">
                    <a href="#tabstrip-home" data-icon="home">Home</a>
                    <a href="#tabstrip-login" data-icon="contacts">Login</a>
                    <a href="#tabstrip-location" data-icon="search">Location</a>
                    <a href="#tabstrip-weather" data-icon="globe">Weather</a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Do you get any errors in the console when you try to run this?

Comment: Junning your json through jsonlint.com, it looks like you are missing one more closing } before the closing ].

Comment: @giltnerj0 that ended up being that so it did can someone please tell me how do i select nested elements like the screen content one?